# sudo apt-get update have error

Tags: raspbian, update, rpi-update

i have error on updating raspberry pi

```
pi@TechTSDHacking:~ $ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://deb.playonlinux.com stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

plz help see attachad image

please help me

Comment: You have a bastardised list of sources. Restore to original or re-install.

Comment: whatever you wanted to get from `deb.playonlinux.com` is not available for raspberry pi period ... only on i386 or amd64 architecture - the real clue is what playonlinux is ... *PlayOnLinux is a piece of software which allows you to easily install and use numerous games and apps designed to run with **Microsoft® Windows®***

Comment: @JaromandaX Move your comment to an answer, because you are totally right!

Comment: @MatsK - I'm not right, google is :

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have an entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` pointing to a repository at `http://deb.playonlinux.com` that  doesn't support architecture 'armhf'. The Raspberry Pi has this architecture so you cannot use this repository. If so, then comment this line and redo:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```